# Changing website Jsoup parses in an if statement

Tags: java, android, jsoup

All- I am parsing data from 21 different addresses depending on what the user selects in a spinner. For example, if the user selects "Eldora" the website it should parse from is http://www.coloradoski.com/resorts/eldora. But if they select "Copper" should parse from http://www.coloradoski.com/resorts/copper. The thing is, only the address changes, not the actual tags. So, I could just copy everything into 21 different classes and just change the address but it seems as if there should be a way to just change the address based on the user selection and not the actual tags. Here is my code:

```
class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {  
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading Data","Getting from http://eldora.com/", true);

        //do initialization of required objects objects here                
    };      
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.coloradoski.com/resorts/eldora").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        docTitle = doc.select("div#column-narrow.grid_310.alpha h1").first().text();
        AnnualSnowfallString = doc.select("dl#mountain-stats dt + dd").first().text();

        AreaString = doc.select("dl#mountain-stats dt + dd + dt + dd ").first().text();
        BaseElevationString = doc.select("dl#mountain-stats dt + dd +dt + dd + dt + dd").first().text();
        SummitElevationString = doc.select("dl#mountain-stats dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd").first().text();
        HoursofOperationString = doc.select("dl#mountain-stats dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd").first().text();
        SeasonDatesString = doc.select("dl#mountain-stats dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd").first().text();
        NotesString = doc.select("dl#mountain-stats dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd + dt + dd").first().text();
        return null;        
    }
```

The `dl#mountain-stats dt + dd + dt + dd` doesn't change from site to site, just the address. Any ideas on how to change only that based on user selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can send parameters to your `AsyncTask`. Change your:

```
class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
```

to

```
class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
```

And now you can send parameters to your `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` function like this:

```
new AddStringTask().execute(STRING_THAT_USER_SELECTED)
```

and in your `doInBackground()` function you can get the passed string with

```
String passedString = unused[0]
```

And under your `progressDialog` variable, define another variable  like `String url` :

```
class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {  
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String url ="http://www.coloradoski.com/resorts/";
```

And after you get the passed string to your asynctask, append the `url` with the passed string and call the `Jsoup's connect()` function.

```
 doc = Jsoup.connect(url+passedString).get();
```

Hope this helps